# How to pass a ctest test action (--test-action) using CMake presets?

Tags: cmake, valgrind, ctest

We're using [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) in our projects for the configuration, build and test steps.

I've recently discovered the [`ctest --test-action memcheck`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#ctest-memcheck-step) facility and would like to define its use in one of our test presets.

From a JSON scheme point of view, I can add [`overwriteConfigurationFile`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#test-preset) parameters, but I fail to see how to invoke the `--test-action` using presets.

`ctest --test-action memcheck --preset name_of_preset` doesn't work either as it seems to ignore the preset content.

How can I define a test action in the preset configuration?

Comment: For reference: I ended up writing my own python script calling clang-tidy as I wanted and wrap it in an `include(CTest)` then `add_test(NAME MyTest COMMAND MyScript.py)` CMakeLists.txt.